# Display initial form.FileField as img tag in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

My form class:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

in the view (GET case) I instance the form (then I pass it to the template ctx):

```
form = MyForm(initial={'image':my_model_obj.image})
```

now in template i wanto to display the image as:

```
<img src="{{form.image.url}}">
```

but that doesn't work, the src just stay blank.

as a workaround I did that in the view:

```
form = MyForm()
form.image_display = my_model_obj.image
```

and in the template:

```
<img src="{{form.image_display.url}}">
```

Is that the way to do it? (I know I can pass the image as a context variable but meh..)

Thank you in advance

Comment: also you can use ModelForm and specify as instance model_obj.pk ...

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this :D just found in docs

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

file_data = {'image': SimpleUploadedFile(my_model_obj.image.name.split('/')[-1], my_model_obj.image.file)}
form = MyForm(file_data)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form